# Adding permissions to the Android Manifest with Apportable

Tags: android, manifest, apportable

I'm trying to follow the Store Kit documentation to make in-app purchases over the apportabled -android version of my app. Most of the steps are pretty simple and I've managed to upload the apk on google developer console.

However, I'm realizing now, when trying to add the in-app products over the developer console, that the generated AndroidManifest.xml does not have the BILLING permission.

My question is, how do I add a permission to the manifest. I can see two potentially related properties in configuration.json (APPLICATION_MANIFEST_EXTRAS and MANIFEST_EXTRAS), but I have no idea how to format the options or if its even related.

Any help would be appreaciated, thanks

Comment: I realize now that all the information is in configuration.json, I'm sorry about the dumb question, I'm very used to googling everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common AndroidManifest.xml features are set up by modifying the features section in configuration.json.

To dive deeper into how the AndroidManifest.xml is created, see  .apportable/SDK/site_scons/android/mainifest.py

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks for the answer! I should've taken the time to look into configuration.json in details before asking the question. Now what I'm actually trying to do is to port an already live iOS game which has in-app products onto Android, and I don't have the names of the in-app products, but I would like to test with fake-products and I really have trouble understanding how apportable would magically translate the requests to the google developer console. How would I query for a specific product ?

Comment: Might be better to create another SO question, but check out http://docs.apportable.com/publishing.html#storekit